# CodeIgniter and Bootstrap modal - passing data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have created a bootstrap modal mngCat that is inside views/modals folder, which I want to call in both cases, when I want to add a new category or when I want to edit an existing category.

```
<div id="mngCat" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 id="addNewLabel"><?php echo empty($cat->category_id) ? 'Add category' : 'Edit category ' . $cat->category; ?></h3>
    </div><!-- end of .modal-header -->
    <div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo form_open('admin/category/manage') . PHP_EOL; ?>
        <p>
        <label for="category_name">Category name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="category_name" value="<?php echo set_value('category_name', $cat->category); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="parent">Set Parent category:</label>
        <select>
        <option>-- None --</option>
        <?php if(count($all_categories)): foreach($all_categories as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat->category_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->category; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
        </select>
        </p>
        <?php echo form_close() . PHP_EOL; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of #mngCat modal -->
```

When I want to add a category I hit this ci anchor

```
$attr = array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'data-toggle' => 'modal',
    'data-target' => '#mngCat'
    );
echo anchor('#mngCat','<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Category', $attr);
```

and when I want to edit a category I hit this:

```
<?php echo anchor('#mngCat' . $cat->category_id, $cat->category, $attr); //not passing any data  ?>
```

So when I click Add Category the modal appears with title Add category, but when I click on the category name (2nd anchor) does not appear the modal. What I'd like to do is to display the modal with the title Edit category  and display in form the category data so that i can do the editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand few things here:

1. bootstrap modal is already loaded in a view or rather its already
   rendered -  its just hidden (do view source you will see it there).
2. No matter how much you click on it and what you do it will always
   display same data
3. you can't parse data to bootstrap modal via link unless you do
   some post procesing.

**What you have to do**

1. using jquery create onclikc event on both your links
2. add `data-category_id=$cat->category_id` as your atribue (if add add null)
3. once a event is triggered,  create a modal

   `var category_modal = $('<div id="mngCat" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>');`
4. load into modal body the data via ajax

   ```
   .post('somecontroler/getcatgoryform/',{category_id:$(this).data('category-id')}
             function(response){
              category_modal.html(response);
              category_modal.modal('show');

   }
   ```

   }

5)  in codigniters  somecontroler/getcatgoryform/ do the processing and
    load the view that starts with modal header (without modal
    container)
 sfsdfsd

```
 <div class="modal-header"><h3 id="addNewLabel"><?php echo empty($cat->category_id) ? 'Add category' : 'Edit category ' . $cat->category; ?></h3></div><!-- end of .modal-header -->
<div class="modal-body">
<?php echo form_open('admin/category/manage') . PHP_EOL; ?>
    <p>
    <label for="category_name">Category name:</label>
<input type="text" name="category_name" value="<?php echo set_value('category_name', $cat->category); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="parent">Set Parent category:</label>
    <select>
    <option>-- None --</option>
    <?php if(count($all_categories)): foreach($all_categories as $cat): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat->category_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->category; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </select>
    </p>
    <?php echo form_close() . PHP_EOL; ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

finally if not sure, google `load bootstrp modal via ajax`

Comment: you said in no2 that the modal will always display same data. So is it better to have two modals instead of one??

Comment: yes. as said - modal is already loaded into HTML.  also it doesn't change  state (because its loaded!). For example: if you click add, add some data, click cancel, and again add - data will be there (modalis just a div elemnt that hides and displays) .  You can have one modal that adds a category, but you also have to add a modal for every  category you want to edit (if it is a category list). Not to mention the problem, with data being persistent in the modal. Thats why it is better to create modal dynamilcy. google `'load bootrrap modal via ajax'`, `load bootstrap modal dynamically`

Comment: oh and about your What to Do section: I'm not very familiar with javascript and jquery, could you explain my more thorough by an example the steps 1-4 basicly??

Comment: google `load bootstrap modal dynamically`, `load bootstra modal with ajax`, `bootstrap modal and ajax`, etc. You have to knpw jqeury in order to perform this.

Comment: also if answer was helpful in any way mark it as answered! you guys give no incentive fro us to help you